# How to get precipitation/rainfall through weather api?

Tags: python, python-requests, weather, weather-api

I tired [Open Weather Map](http://openweathermap.org/current) because the docs say it has "rain", but when I call it it doesn't. So I tried [Python Weather API](https://code.google.com/p/python-weather-api/wiki/Examples) but none of those options from weather.com, noaa, or yahoo weather have rainfall or precipitation. So I tried [Wunderground](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=index&MR=1) but that only seems to work for US cities, and on top of that I can't be bothered buying a key.

Anyone know where to go from here?

On open weather map it says it has rain, but I don't get that in the results:

Example of JSON call

```
{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},
"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},
"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"main":{"temp":289.5,"humidity":89,"pressure":1013,"temp_min":287.04,"temp_max":292.04},
"wind":{"speed":7.31,"deg":187.002},
"rain":{"3h":0},                      # on this line
"clouds":{"all":92},
"dt":1369824698,
"id":1851632,
"name":"Shuzenji", 
"cod":200}
```

However, when I call it like so

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Vancouver')
pprint(r.json())
```

I get something with no rainfall/precipitation.

```
{u'base': u'cmc stations',
 u'clouds': {u'all': 0},
 u'cod': 200,
 u'coord': {u'lat': 49.25, u'lon': -123.12},
 u'dt': 1406042326,
 u'id': 6173331,
 u'main': {u'humidity': 77,
           u'pressure': 862,
           u'temp': 289.33,
           u'temp_max': 290.93,
           u'temp_min': 288.15},
 u'name': u'Vancouver',
 u'sys': {u'country': u'CA',
          u'message': 0.1867,
          u'sunrise': 1406032353,
          u'sunset': 1406088323},
 u'weather': [{u'description': u'Sky is Clear',
               u'icon': u'01d',
               u'id': 800,
               u'main': u'Clear'}],
 u'wind': {u'deg': 104.001, u'speed': 2.75}}
```

Comment: You can use [Ambee’s weather API](https://www.getambee.com/api/weather). They provide accurate weather data with the type of precipitation and intensity in any location of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://openweathermap.org/weather-data), `weather`, `rain.3h`, and `snow.3h` are all `optional` parameters, suggesting that they will not always be included in the result.

I interpret that to mean that rain and snow won't be reported if there was no rain or snow at the time in question -- such as in your example where it says "Sky is clear" -- but it's also possible that it means they just don't guarantee rain/snow data.

Comment: I'm not sure. It started raining like crazy where I am so I tested it out and there's still no key for rain.

Comment: Usually the rain field will be reported on after accumulating the rainfall value over a period of a few hours. In OpenWeatherMap this is 3 hours.

Comment: That's really weird though, are their water bottles  unable to support basic measurements and servers - speculative results? Reporting (value, speculative: bool)  every few minutes in realtime would allow so much more... But eh, this isn't UX discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I found the rain;) It was not easy, but it succeeded. It exists.

```
    fetch(https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    const { pressure, temp, humidity } = data.main;
    const { speed, deg } = data.wind;
    const { description } = data.weather[0];
    const rain = data.rain['1h'];
    console.log(rain)
  });
```